# Country Of Departure Srilankan ETA

Tags: eta, sri-lanka

Need some help on what to put in country of departure. this is an online form For Srilankan Electronic travel authorization .

i will be traveling to Thailand , will be staying there for 4 days and then will travel to Srilanka by air

The form asks for
"Where you have been during last 14 days before this travel*"
see attached screenshot.

should i put Thailand OR my home country where i will be starting by journey from.

[image: Srilanka ETA form Country of departure]

Comment: In my experience with similar forms, they recognize that you can be somewhere for a shorter period and therefore allow you to add multiple responses.  Are you certain that it's not possible to add a second response after entering one?

Comment: @phoog , i don't see any option to add more than one , if you want to check that , https://eta.gov.lk/etaslvisa/etaNavServ?payType=1  and select apply for a group

Comment: I think you're right, there doesn't seem to be any such option.

Comment: it is "Thailand"